# Can push notification be caught and suppressed

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I have a scenario where if a push notification arrives I'd like to suppress it and show at later time, is that possible?

Comment: No, You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

As say in comments, you can't do it.

Actually it's apple stuff, you can't do anything but send notification. It's the user that decide whenever he wants to see or not notifications from your app.

Your app can change the badge number on its icon and send -eventually- local notification. And your server can send push notification, that can change the badge too. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are designed to work even if your app is inactive. They happen on a system level, so you cannot have them execute custom code.

You can, however, device scheme to have your user react to certain conditions and activate your app (e.g. local notifications) which could then disable them.